# How to pass TextInput value in React native to mobx action?

Tags: reactjs, native, mobx

I want to pass the value of the text input to the TestStore (mobx) to basically alert the value that was entered please can anyone tell me how I achieve this.

Thanks

I have the following code:

Home.js:

```
<TextInput style={[
  !this.state.email ? { borderWidth: 3, borderColor: 'red' } : null]}
  onChangeText={(text) => this.validate(text, 'email')}
  value={this.state.email}
  maxLength={100} 
/>

<TouchableOpacity style={
  [{
    width: '70%',
    backgroundColor: this.state.buttonInvalid ? '#607D8B' : '#009688' }
  ]} 
  activeOpacity={.5}
  disabled={this.state.buttonInvalid}
  onPress={this.props.testStore.alert}
>
  <Text>Submit</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

TestStore.js:

```
 import { observable, action } from "mobx";

 export default class TestStore {

   @observable email = null;
     @action alert = () => {  
        alert('The value you entered is '); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, resolved it amended the button to the following code:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={
  [{
    width: '70%',
    backgroundColor: this.state.buttonInvalid ? '#607D8B' : '#009688' }
  ]} 
  activeOpacity={.5}
  disabled={this.state.buttonInvalid}
 onPress={() => this.props.testStore.alert(this.state.email)}
>
  <Text>Submit</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```